# Why does \expandafter work with \uppercase, but not with \textbf for instance?

Tags: expansion, expandafter

Why does \expandafter work with \uppercase, but not with \textbf?

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\name{hello world}

\textbf\expandafter{\name}

\uppercase\expandafter{\name}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't really know why, but `\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\name}` works.

Comment: So does `\textbf{\name}`, but not `\uppercase{\name}`.

Comment: `\textbf{...}` is eqivalent to `{\bfseries ...}` but the implmentation is anything but simple.  `\uppercase` is a TeX command which doesn't expand the text.

Comment: Not related to the question but always use `\MakeUppercase`  in latex not `\uppercase` see `\uppercase{Erdős} \MakeUppercase{Erdős}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any TeX *primitive* that requires a ⟨general text⟩ has the same feature: in order to find the tokens that primitive should operate on, TeX performs macro expansion, ignoring space and `\relax` tokens as it goes, until it finds `{` (meaning either an explicit character token with category code 1 or a token `\let` to such character).

Besides `\uppercase` and `\lowercase` also

- ⟨token variable⟩
- `\message` and `\errmessage`
- `\write`
- `\special`
- `\mark` and `\marks` (*)
- `\unexpanded` (*)
- `\detokenize` (*)
- `\scantokens` (*)
- `\showtokens` (*)
- `\expanded` (*)

have the same property. The primitives marked with (*) aren't in Knuth TeX. Note that a ⟨general text⟩ must end with ⟨right brace⟩, which means an *explicit* character token of category 2. For instance

```
\def\foo{{foo}}
\uppercase\foo
\uppercase\relax\foo
```

will result in printing `FOOFOO`, but note the inner braces in the definition of `\foo`. With

```
\uppercase\expandafter{\name}
```

it's similar: since `\expandafter` is expandable, TeX performs the relevant action, which is to expand (one-level) the token following the next one (so `{` is jumped over and `\name` is expanded) and to vanish. Thus the main token list has

```
\uppercase{hello world}
```

and `\uppercase` can start its job: TeX looks up to the matching `}`, sends the tokens to the stomach, which will apply the `\uccode` equivalents and send back the result to the main token list; `\uppercase` and the braces have now disappeared and the result is

```
HELLO WORLD
```

Without `\expandafter`, the stomach would see `\name` to which it does nothing, because there's no character token hence it is sent back unchanged.

What's a ⟨token variable⟩? An example is `\everymath`, whereby

```
\everymath=\expandafter{\the\everymath ⟨other tokens⟩}
```

would append ⟨other tokens⟩ to the current contents of `\everymath` (the `=` is optional). Any ⟨token parameter⟩, `\toks⟨number⟩` command and all tokens defined with `\toksdef`, usually via `\newtoks`, are instances of a ⟨token variable⟩; besides `\everymath`, there are other eight instances of `⟨token parameter⟩` listed on page 275 of the TeXbook.

To the contrary, `\textbf` is, from a practical point of view, a macro with one argument and so, by the rules of TeX about undelimited arguments,

```
\textbf\expandafter{\name}
```

would grab `\expandafter` as the argument and you have the same effect as

```
\textbf{\expandafter}{\name}
```

and the action of this `\expandafter` is just to expand an `\else` or a `\fi` a bit earlier than usual:

```
\ifmmode
  \nfss@text
  {\bfseries\expandafter}% <--- from #1
\else
  \hmode@bgroup
    \text@command{\expandafter}% <--- from #1
    \bfseries\check@icl\expandafter % <--- from #1
    \check@icr
    \expandafter\egroup
\fi
```

(as far as I can see, `\text@command{\expandafter}` would do nothing dangerous, but nothing useful either). Strictly speaking, `\textbf` has no argument, but its expansion is `\protect\textbf•` (the bullet denotes a space in the name) and it's `\textbf•` that takes one argument, but this is mostly irrelevant for the topic.

Note also that

```
\expandafter\uppercase\expandafter{\name}
```

works as well as

```
\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\name}
```

but in the former the first `\expandafter` is redundant, while in the latter both are redundant, because `\textbf` essentially opens a group where `\bfseries` comes into force and the argument is typeset, as usual with macro expansion. Yes, `\textbf` does a bunch of other things as you see from the code above (replace the first three `\expandafter` tokens with `\name`), but I guess you used `\textbf` just by way of example. Indeed, the same applies to every *macro* taking one or more arguments.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the answer is just "given the internal implementation, the TeXbook states it would be".

First, `\uppercase` is a primitive TeX command, whose syntax is `\uppercase ⟨general text⟩`. So it will expand the following tokens in the input stream until it finds some `{` (any token with bgroup meaning). (TeXbook chapter 24 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267413/250119)

In this case `\expandafter` is required because otherwise `\uppercase` will be applied on the token list `\name` instead of
the token list `hello world`, which will not have the desired effect of capitalizing the text inside.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199783/250119.

In the other case `\textbf` is defined as...

```
$ latexdef textbf

\textbf:
macro:->\protect \textbf  


\textbf :
\long macro:#1->\ifmmode \nfss@text {\bfseries #1}\else \hmode@bgroup \text@command {#1}\bfseries \check@icl #1\check@icr \expandafter \egroup \fi
```

Given the rules that TeX use to grab undelimited argument, `\expandafter` will be grabbed as the argument and the following part is not made bold.

Remark: there may be some LaTeX commands whose implementation makes it so that `\command \expandafter { ... }` might just-happen to work properly (e.g. `\exp_not:n`), but unless it's explicitly documented as part of the command behavior, it's better to refrain from using it.

In this case simply using `\textbf{\name}` works.
Alternative includes `\expandafter\textbf\expandafter{\name}`, `\ExpandArgs{o}\textbf{\name}` or `\ExpandArgs{v}\textbf\name` if it's necessary to pass the value of `\name` into the command.